# How to send an image using websockets in java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am trying to send an image by drag and drop in send message area but its failing to do so. I dont know how to send an image in this code. Can someone please help me out?

ChatEndpoint.java
This is serverendpoint of websocket.I have four methods.onOpen,onClose,onMessage and onError.I am not doing anything in onOpen method.This method gets called when websocket establishes the connection.When the websocket tries to send message to the client,onMessage method gets called.Here the message sent from the jsp page(client) sends it in json string format to the server.The object mapper converts it to java object.I have also made an enum for MessageType having two options LOGIN and MESSAGE.I am checking inf the java object matches with the login message type then it stores the name of chat user from properties of user obtained from session object.It also then sends the session object to join method where the session is added to the list of session object.It also send the message the user has joined the chat room.If messagetype is a message then it sends it to send message method of room class where the message is sent back to the client using sendText.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class ChatEndpoint {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ChatEndpoint.class.getSimpleName());
    private Room room = Room.getRoom();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(final Session session, EndpointConfig config) {}

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final Session session, final String messageJson) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ChatMessage chatMessage = null;
        try {
            chatMessage = mapper.readValue(messageJson, ChatMessage.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String message = "Badly formatted message";
            try {
                session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.CANNOT_ACCEPT, message));
            } catch (IOException ex) { log.severe(ex.getMessage()); }
        } ;

        Map<String, Object> properties = session.getUserProperties();
        if (chatMessage.getMessageType() == MessageType.LOGIN) {
            String name = chatMessage.getMessage();
            properties.put("name", name);
            room.join(session);
            room.sendMessage(name + " - Joined the chat room");
        }
        else {
            String name = (String)properties.get("name");
            room.sendMessage(name + " - " + chatMessage.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void OnClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        room.leave(session);
        room.sendMessage((String)session.getUserProperties().get("name") + " - Left the room");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable ex) { log.info("Error: " + ex.getMessage()); }


}
```

Room.java

```
public class Room {
    private static Room instance = null;
    private List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();

    public synchronized void join(Session session) { sessions.add(session); }
    public synchronized void leave(Session session) { sessions.remove(session); }
    public synchronized void sendMessage(String message) {
        for (Session session: sessions) {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                try { session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message); }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized static Room getRoom() {
        if (instance == null) { instance = new Room(); }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

index.jsp
Here i am sending the wsUri which is stored in context param as ws://localhost:8080/single-room-chat/chat

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<% String WsUrl = getServletContext().getInitParameter("WsUrl"); %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0,
    width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>
<title>single-room-chat</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/styles/site.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/chatroom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var wsUri = '<%=WsUrl%>';
var proxy = CreateProxy(wsUri);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('loginPanel'));
    proxy.initiate({
        loginPanel: document.getElementById('loginPanel'),
        msgPanel: document.getElementById('msgPanel'),
        txtMsg: document.getElementById('txtMsg'),
        txtLogin: document.getElementById('txtLogin'),
        msgContainer: document.getElementById('msgContainer')
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="loginPanel">
        <div id="infoLabel">Type a name to join the room</div>
        <div style="padding: 10px;">
            <input id="txtLogin" type="text" class="loginInput"
                onkeyup="proxy.login_keyup(event)" />
            <button type="button" class="loginInput" onclick="proxy.login()">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="msgPanel" style="display: none">
        <div id="msgContainer" style="overflow: auto;"></div>
        <div id="msgController">
            <textarea id="txtMsg" 
                title="Enter to send message"
                onkeyup="proxy.sendMessage_keyup(event)"
                style="height: 20px; width: 100%"></textarea>
            <button style="height: 30px; width: 100px" type="button"
                onclick="proxy.logout()">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

chatroom.js

```
var CreateProxy = function(wsUri) {
    var websocket = null;
    var audio = null;
    var elements = null;

    var playSound = function() {
        if (audio == null) {
            audio = new Audio('content/sounds/beep.wav');
        }

        audio.play();
    };

    var showMsgPanel = function() {
            elements.loginPanel.style.display = "none";
            elements.msgPanel.style.display = "block";
            elements.txtMsg.focus();
    };

    var hideMsgPanel = function() {
            elements.loginPanel.style.display = "block";
            elements.msgPanel.style.display = "none";
            elements.txtLogin.focus();
    };

    var displayMessage = function(msg) {
        if (elements.msgContainer.childNodes.length == 100) {
            elements.msgContainer.removeChild(elements.msgContainer.childNodes[0]);
        }

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'msgrow';
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(msg);
        div.appendChild(textnode); 
        elements.msgContainer.appendChild(div);

        elements.msgContainer.scrollTop = elements.msgContainer.scrollHeight;
    };

    var clearMessage = function() {
        elements.msgContainer.innerHTML = '';
    };

    return {
        login: function() {
            elements.txtLogin.focus();

            var name = elements.txtLogin.value.trim();
            if (name == '') { return; }

            elements.txtLogin.value = '';

            // Initiate the socket and set up the events
            if (websocket == null) {
                websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

                websocket.onopen = function() {
                    var message = { messageType: 'LOGIN', message: name };
                    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                };
                websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
                    displayMessage(e.data);
                    showMsgPanel();
                    playSound();
                };
                websocket.onerror = function(e) {};
                websocket.onclose = function(e) {
                    websocket = null;
                    clearMessage();
                    hideMsgPanel();
                };
            }
        },
        sendMessage: function() {
            elements.txtMsg.focus();

            if (websocket != null && websocket.readyState == 1) {
                var input = elements.txtMsg.value.trim();
                if (input == '') { return; }

                elements.txtMsg.value = '';

                var message = { messageType: 'MESSAGE', message: input };

                // Send a message through the web-socket
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            }
        },
        login_keyup: function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) { this.login(); } },
        sendMessage_keyup: function(e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) { this.sendMessage(); } },
        logout: function() {
            if (websocket != null && websocket.readyState == 1) { websocket.close();}
        },
        initiate: function(e) {
            elements = e;
            elements.txtLogin.focus();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey OP, it would be incredibly helpful if you could narrow down your issue a lot. You've pasted a lot of code here, it surely can't all be linked to your problem.

Comment: I posted a lot of code  to make others understand my problem much better.